# Is there a SASS/CSS selector for items WITHOUT a particular adjacent sibling?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, siblings

I want to put a top border on all `<li>` elements with class "foo" that are NOT an adjacent sibling of a `<li>` element with class "bar".

Is there a "without adjacent sibling [x]" SASS/CSS selector? Or is the only way to accomplish this via two rules, one to add the top border to all `<li class="foo">`s and another to take it away from the `<li>` next to `<li class="bar">`?

Answer (score 1):

When i undersdood corretly, you want to have this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gECc9/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="bar">Bar</li>
    <li class="foo">foo</li>
    <li class="foo">foo</li>
    <li class="foo">foo</li>
    <li class="foo">foo</li>
    <li class="bar">Bar</li>
    <li class="foo">foo</li>
    <li class="foo">foo</li>
    <li class="foo">foo</li>
    <li class="foo">foo</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li:not(.bar)+li.foo
{
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
```

The selector that selects each `<li class="foo">` that is not an adjacent sibling of `<li class="bar">`

This selector has only the weakness of needing one leading `<li>`. If the first item is not a `<li class="bar">` the item will be left out. This can be addressed like seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gECc9/1/

```
li:not(.bar)+li.foo,
li.foo:first-child
{
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
```

P.S. when you want to group items inside a list you could also use definition lists `<dl>` or nested lists. This could prevent problems like these.